# Difference between linear virtual address and virtual address

Tags: memory, computer-architecture

Can anyone explaine me a difference between linear virtual address and virtual address ?  I can't understand this difference.

Comment: Not all virtual addresses need be linear. Segment/Offset forms for example. Without a specific context, I think that's all te answer you can expect.

Comment: Could you tell more about: `Segment/Offset forms for example` ?  Simply, I can't tell a difference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical reasons, Intel 80386 and later processors implement virtual memory not only by paging, but also support the [memory segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) used by earlier x86 processors.

This means that addresses go through two mapping steps, segment/offset (which results in a linear virtual address), and paging (which results in the physical address).

Most other CPUs do no have segmentation, and have only linear addresses and physical addresses.

In other words, linear virtual addresses and virtual addresses are exactly the same; Intel adds "linear" only to differentiate them from segment/offset (virtual) addresses.

Comment: So, linear virtual address is the same as virtual address. Word 'linear' tell us that address was mapped by segmentation ?  Now, this address will be mapped by pagination in traditional way.  Correct?

Comment: Actually, "linear" just means that it is not a segmented address. In 64-bit mode, there is no segment mapping.

Comment: So linear virtual means the same as virtual ?

Comment: Segment/offset addresses also could be described as virtual.

Comment: *Segment/offset addresses*. I can' understand it. What does it mean ?

Comment: The answer links to the description. And if you aren't using x86, don't bother.